# Regex for GCP log search "not in"

Tags: regex, logging, google-cloud-platform

We have GCP logs like

- Hi my name is 'adam'
- Hi my name is 'adam'
- Hi my name is 'steve'

I'd like to find all logs that match this exact pattern except for the name being 'adam'.  For example, would only keep `Hi my name is 'steve'`.

In GCP legacy logs viewer, I've tried the following search to no avail

```
Hi my name is '[^a]'
Hi my name is '[^adam]'
Hi my name is '^((?!adam).)*$'
```

Pretty bad at regex in general, and not sure that GCP parses them identically to other https://regexr.com/ default settings that I've been testing on.  Am I offbase entirely or should one of these more or less work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were getting closer with your last attempt. If I understand what you want correctly, you could use one of the following expressions:

**Adam surrounded by single quotes:**

```regex
^Hi my name is '(?!adam)[^']*'
```

Here's a breakdown of this expression:

```
Hi my name is '        #Match some static text
(?!adam)               #Ensure the word 'adam' doesn't appear at this point.
[^']*                  #Match all characters until you encounter a single quote.
'                      #Match a single quote.
```

**Adam without single quotes:**

```regex
^Hi my name is (?!adam)[^\n]*
```

Here's a breakdown of this expression:

```
Hi my name is          #Match some static text
(?!adam)               #Ensure the word 'adam' doesn't appear at this point.
[^\n]*                 #Match all characters until you encounter a newline.
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think I may have complicated it further with the quotes.  What if it was just `Hi I am adam nice to meet you` and I wanted to screen all that didn't have adam at this position?  Or more simply, what if there were no single quotes (ie apostrophe)?  Would that simplify your answer?

Comment: As regular expressions go, I think the one in  my answer is very simple. The single quotes don't make it that much more complicated in my opinion. If you don't have the single quotes, you could use something like this `^Hi my name is (?!adam)[^\n]*$`.

Comment: I missed that you changed the containing phrase in your comment. What are the rules that you need to enforce? Is detecting the presence of the word adam anywhere in the sentence enough?

Answer (score 2):

You might optionally match the quotes, and after that check for `adam`. If the assertion succeeds, then match the rest of the line.

```
\bHi my name is ["']*\b(?!adam\b).+
```

- `\bHi my name is`  Match the string preceded by a word boundary
- `["']*\b` Optionally match a single or double quote followed by a word boundary
- `(?!adam\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not `adam` directly to the right
- `.+` Match 1+ times any character except a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QtlQzB/1)